# How to match substring that ends with comma or end of line?

Tags: java, regex

I want to parse out all attributes from the LDAP distinguished name. The attribute starts with comman or the line begin, ends with comma or the line end.

I've written the following:

```
    String patternStr = "[^,][A-Z]+=([A-Za-z0-9]+)[,$]";
    String str = "CN=USERID003,OU=Users,DC=intern,DC=mycompany,DC=pl";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr);
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(str);
    while (m.find()) {
        String substr = str.substring(m.start(), m.end());
        System.out.println(substr);
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```

The output is:

```
CN=USERID003,
USERID003
OU=Users,
Users
DC=intern,
intern
DC=mycompany,
mycompany
```

Matching of the start with `[^,]` functions correctly, but the block `[,$]` is matching only commans, not the end of the line.

How to match as the substring end both comma and the line end?

Comment: A last note: [^,] does *not* match a line/string start or a comma: it matches *any character except comma*. The wildcard `[,$]` matches a comma or a dollar; inside `[]` the usual magic character bestiary is not in effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you want according to your *description*

```
String patternStr = "(?:^|,)[A-Z]+=([A-Za-z0-9]+)(?:,|$)";
```

Match starts at a begin of line/string *or* comma, and ends at a comma or end of line/string.

Answer (score 2):

I would advise you to forget about the pattern and matcher and use `String.split()` instead - it gives all the functionality that you want and the code is more readable.

```
String str = "CN=USERID003,OU=Users,DC=intern,DC=mycompany,DC=pl";
String[] attrs = str.split(",")
for (String attr : attrs) {
    System.out.println(attr);
    System.out.println(attr.split("=")[1])
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I want regex because I can quickly adapt it to matching only a specific attribute. With split, I'd have to manually search the return array comparing the attribute names etc. I don't want to write a parser, when it's already written :)

Answer (score 1):

Why wouldn't you use [str.split()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) ? And then use "for" to search all " XX = YYYY ", and then split again if you only need the attribute name or its value.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
[^,][A-Z]+=([A-Za-z0-9]+)(?:,|(?=$))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this lookbehind based regex for matching:

```
(?<=,|^)([^=]+)=([^,]*)
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/fA9gC1/2)

**Code:**

```
String patternStr = "(?<=,|^)([^=]+)=([^,]*)";
String str = "CN=USERID003,OU=Users,DC=intern,DC=mycompany,DC=pl";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr);
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.printf("%s : %s%n", m.group(1), m.group(2)); 
}
```

**Output:**

```
CN : USERID003
OU : Users
DC : intern
DC : mycompany
DC : pl
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex: `(.+?,)|(.+)`

Check it out here: http://www.regexr.com/399a7

Answer (score 0):

You could change your pattern `"[^,][A-Z]+=([A-Za-z0-9]+)[,$]"`
to `"(?:^|,)[A-Z]+=([A-Za-z0-9]+)(?:,|$)"`

Then, you'll get your desired results.

I guess your previous problem is:
In [...] Character Grouping, only Characters are included, not 'Boundary matchers'.
Meanwhile, [^,]  means any characters except ','.  while [,$] means character',' or character '$', no any boundary-matchers meaning.